# How to check if the url is used and not valid after 24 hours?

Tags: java, android, ios, struts2

I am building a webapp using Java struts. How to do the following?

1) When the website sends change forgotten password email, I want to make it valid only for 24 hours and make the url invalid once the user has changed his password. How to do this? ANy online code?

2) In what way I should have my website built(as far I researched I knew I should use JSON) so that the android app and ios app also shows same data as in the website.

I just want the minimal front end and user authentication in the mobile app. Rest all(I mean validation, authentication, authorization) should be via the web site. So how should I develop the website. What technologies and APIs I should use? How should I use JSON for this? Any sample webapp and android app explaining this.

Comment: there is anything regarding ios?

Comment: yes. I am also going to build an iphone app. So it should show the same website data

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to build is as follows

1. Use the elapsed time as a reference.
2. Get the current elapsed time as string. (e.g. in Java you can do `String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())`).
3. Now encode this string, say [AES Encryption](http://techie-experience.blogspot.in/2012/10/encryption-and-decryption-using-aes.html) with some secret key.
4. Pass this string as query string parameter in the URL (e.g. www.myserver.com/forgotPassword?q=HGFreSD654FDHK) .
5. When user clicks the link, you get this encrypted string. Decrypt  it and compare that with current time.
6. If the time elapsed is more that 24 hours send the appropriate error message else proceed.

**EDIT:**
For SMS based token as OP has indicated, then generate the token and store them with current time in database against the username and verify the same when the same token.

Comment: I have two questions.
1) The System.currentTimeMillis() would be server time right?
2) May I know what is mean by elapsed time?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` will give you the time elapsed in millisecs since 1970. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Comment: Thanks Santhosh. My web app will be sending a 6 digit numeric code as SMS to the user's mobile number. User needs to enter it within next 5 mins in the website to sign up. Could you help me in this use case. I have no idea as there is no URL here.

Comment: I thought of saving the time the webapp sends text to the user in the database and get the system time when the user enters the code. If it is less than 5 mins, then approve it, else resend the code. I would like to know some other approach which may be much simpler.

Comment: Well, if SMS tokens are involved then database is the right and full proof way.

Comment: Thanks again. May I know what you mean by OP in your reply. "For SMS based token as OP has indicated".

Comment: OP = Other Person (generally the person asking question), is a convention community follows on stackoverflow